# Displaying TimeSpan Model in View with format mask mm:ss

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, data-annotations, timespan

I have a TimeSpan Model that I am trying to display in a View (@Html.EditorFor) with a masked format of mm:ss (duration measured in minutes and seconds). I DO NOT want/need hours or AM/PM, but my View without exception displays the mask = "--:-- --" which is the default format "hh:ss tt". I cannot get it to display ANY OTHER masked format. See below for Model and View. I have completely run out of ideas here. Please help!

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm\\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public TimeSpan? LengthAct { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LengthAct, new { htmlattributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_val = "true", data_val_required = "Length is required" } })
```

Comment: Try to do this:

    `public TimeSpan? LengthAct 
    { 
    get { return Time.ToString().Substring(3); } 
    set {} 
    }`

Comment: @Sam have you tried to use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor() seems to kill the data annotations all together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting MVC model TimeSpan field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571291/formatting-mvc-model-timespan-field)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LengthAct, "{0:mm\\:ss}")
```

Greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `DataType.Time` to the property, and then render it with `EditorFor`, you're going to get an HTML5 time input. In supported browsers, this will often be presented to the user as a formatted control allowing you type the hours and minutes individually. At least if the browser is using an en-US local, the time will be 12-hour format, and there will be an AM/PM selector, as well. I'm not sure what browsers like Chrome display in other locales, as I haven't personally tried it. I'm assuming if the locale uses 24-hour time, you wouldn't have an AM/PM selector, but I'm just guessing.

Regardless, the point is that all the stuff you say you don't want is actually part of the browser's built in control. If you don't like it, your only real option is to use an input of type `text`. You'll need to either remove the `DataType` annotation (although that will affect validation of the field) or use `Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `Html.EditorFor`.

Comment: If I remove `DataType.Time` will the annotation below apply a mask to the textboxfor?

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm\\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: No, `DisplayFormat` doesn't have any effect on the input type used. However, now that I think about it, removing the `DataType` annotation might not work. `EditorFor` also considers the property type, and since you're dealing with a `TimeSpan`, it might still using the `time` type. The safest bet is to just use `TextBoxFor`, since that will always use the `text` type unless you pass a different type in the `htmlAttributes` param.

Comment: So then I lose the masking I was hoping for..Still confused.

Comment: You'll need to use `DisplayFormat` whichever path you take.