# To display --:-- in textbox for entering time

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to display --:-- to --:-- in textbox for timeband in my page and let the user enter the time in hh:mm-hh:mm format (in ASP.Net Web Forms (c#)).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting MVC model TimeSpan field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571291/formatting-mvc-model-timespan-field)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't worked for me, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Then please give us example of your code and describe a problem you have faced.

Comment: I am not using MVC coding into it. i just wanted to know, it is possible to do so without using mvc framework.

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Web Forms?

Comment: Set masks for your textboxes. For example you can use [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin.

Comment: yes asp.net web forms, masks using ajax control??

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this, add **MaskedTextBox** for your application. if you need further validation you can use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use masking for this. Below code for phone no, you can change for time format , see below links.

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskSuperPhone" runat="server"
                   TargetControlID="txtSuperPhone"
                   ClearMaskOnLostFocus ="false"
                   MaskType="None"
                   Mask="(999)999-9999" 
                   MessageValidatorTip="true"
                   InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                   ErrorTooltipEnabled="True">
  </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

[Mask Textbox view for a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258709/mask-textbox-view-for-a-phone-number)

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/

Check this link of with search text "MaskType=Time – Empty mask characters will be filled with the current time"

http://ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-masked-edit-tutorial-example-in-asp-net-c/

Answer (score 0):

Use this pluging https://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bEJB2/382/

```
$(".timepicker").mask("hh:mm");
```